# Find $U=\min\left \{ X,Y\right \}$ , $V=\max\left \{ X,Y\right \}$.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, correlation

First of all, I'm apologizing for such a basic question.

I've just started with probability & statistics and I came across this example:

Let $X, Y$ be random indpendent variables defined with
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
\frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Let $U=\min\left \{  X,Y\right \}$ , $V=\max\left \{  X,Y\right \}$.
Find the correlation coefficient $\rho_{U,V}$

I know how to calculate $\rho_{U,V}$ ,but what I don't know is how to determine $U$ and $V$?

Comment: How do you define $X$ and $Y$ with that matrix?

Comment: How on Earth can the text of your question lead to the first sentence of the answer below, which you accepted immediately by the way?

Comment: Because I've got the solution for this example,but there's no explanation how U & V are determined @Did

Comment: @Did I agree that the question is incorrectly stated. I just guessed and answered according to what I felt might be the question.

Comment: @Amit Then you might want to share with the rest of us mere mortals how you came to the conclusion that the matrix in the question was describing a pair of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables?

Comment: @DraganZrilić Huh? But if one thing is clear, it is how $U$ and $V$ are defined. The rest, by contrast...

Comment: @Did Sometimes problems need to be guessed. Being a teacher I come across situations like these many times when I have to think what a student want to ask. Anyways to answer your question you may think that I have solved a correct problem that is "reasonably" close to the stated wrong problem hoping that it can be of some help to the person who posted it.

Comment: @Did Why is it a reasonable guess? Before the matrix, the question also states that X and Y are random independent variables. So, if the first row of the matrix is read as values that these variables take and the second row is read as probabilities then its not a bad guess.

Comment: @Amit Except that it is rather unusual to describe finite distributions by matrices with two rows. Any reference where this is done?

Comment: @Did It is unusual. I never saw finite distributions expressed in this way anywhere before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are iid Bernoulli$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ i.e. joint probability mass function of the two random variables is
$p_{X,Y}(a, b) = \frac{1}{4}$ for $a\in\{0,1\}$ and $b\in\{0,1\}$.

Joint distribution of $U = \min\{X, Y\}$ and $V = \max\{X, Y\}$ is therefore
$p_{U,V}(0, 0) = \Pr(U = 0, V = 0) = \Pr(X = 0, Y = 0) = \frac{1}{4}$
$p_{U,V}(0, 1) = \Pr(U = 0, V = 1) = \Pr(X = 0, Y = 1) + \Pr(X = 1, Y = 0)= \frac{1}{2}$
$p_{U,V}(1, 1) = \Pr(U = 1, V = 1) = \Pr(X = 1, Y = 1) = \frac{1}{4}$

Marginal distribution of $V$ is 
$p_V(0) =\frac{1}{4}$ and $p_V(1) =\frac{3}{4}$
In other words, $V$ is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$

and marginal distribution of $U$ is 
$p_U(0) =\frac{3}{4}$ and $p_U(1) =\frac{1}{4}$
i.e., $U$ is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$

Since $UV = U$, distribution of the product $UV$ is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$.

To calculate the correlation between $U$ and $V$, we will find the Covariance between $U$ and $V$ and variance of $U$ and variance of $V$.

$Cov(U, V) = \mathbb{E}(UV) - \mathbb{E}(U)\mathbb{E}(V) = \frac{1}{4} - \left(\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}\right) =\frac{1}{16} $

$\mathbb{V}(U) = \mathbb{E}(U^2) - (\mathbb{E}(U))^2 = \frac{1}{4} - \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 =\frac{3}{16} $

$\mathbb{V}(V) = \mathbb{E}(V^2) - (\mathbb{E}(V))^2 = \frac{3}{4} - \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 =\frac{3}{16} $.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\rho_{U,V} = \frac{Cov(U, V)}{\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(U)\mathbb{V}(V)}} = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Can you explain me why you have $Pr(X = 1, Y = 1) + Pr(X = 1, Y = 1)$ instead of just one $Pr(X = 1, Y = 1)$ and what about $p_{U,V}(1, 0)$ ?

Comment: It was a typo. Thanks, let me correct it.

Comment: $p_{U,V}(1,0) = 0$ because $\min(X, Y) \leq \max(X, Y)$.